# Symfony 2 - multi-step registration

Tags: symfony2, регистрация, sonata

Доброго времени суток. Появилась необходимость быстро реализовать регистрацию на Симфони 2.6.
Все бы ничего, да вот необходимо это сделать в виде нескольких шагов.

далее =>далее <=> далее <=> подтвердить.

Может быть, кто-нибудь с подобным сталкивался ? 
Сейчас пытаюсь прикрутить [CraueFormFlowBundle](https://github.com/craue/CraueFormFlowBundle) ...пока безуспешно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пфф... Короче, просто переписал контроллер регистрации - и все стало на свои места. 
Вот.

Извините, психанул. ))

Comment: @Станислав Комар, если не затруднит, расскажите подробнее. Я давно хочу на симфони перелезть, и всякие такие штуки мне интересны.

Comment: Ну, в этом плане все просто; 
Сначала изучите что есть сервис. Любой сервис Вы можете переопределить либо наследовать.

Собственно, в регистрации нету ничего сложного. Вы проверяете форму и исходя из бизнес-логики строите ответ клиенту.

Если будут более точные вопросы - с готовностью отвечу.

Comment: если Вы закрываете свой вопрос - было бы не плохо поделится решением)